# How to configure EclipseLink history policy for a lot of entities?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, history

I want to use EclipseLink history policy for tracking history of changes over entity but I have more than 50 entity in my project. Do I have to implement Customizer class per entity like example shown below or can I use more generic method.

Any documentations or suggestions would be appreciated.

*HumanResource_EmployeeCustomizer.java*

```
public class HumanResource_EmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("START");
        policy.addEndFieldName("END");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("EMPLOYEE", "HUMANRESOURCE_EMPLOYEE_");
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

*HumanResource_JobDetailCustomizer.java*

```
public class HumanResource_JobDetailCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("START");
        policy.addEndFieldName("END");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("JOBDETAIL", "HUMANRESOURCE_JOBDETAIL_");
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a session customizer, and iterate over all the descriptors for the classes you want: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Customizers

Comment: @Chris thank you for your response, you have made my day. Thanks a lot.